# Chrome: Changing Select Value with jQuery is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, magento, html-select

This code worked in IE, FF, and Safari (windows7).

It is not working in Chrome however.

Basically, I am trying to make some changes on page load (Magento product page).  I change the selected option (of a hidden select dropdown), then when they hover over the Add to Cart button, I make sure that an option was selected.

Code below:

```
$j('select#attribute76').val( $j('a'+hash).attr('index') ).change();
alert($j('select#attribute76').val()); // shows correctly w/ all browsers
```

... then later on ...

```
 $j('#addtocartbutton').hover(function(){
      //alert($j('select#attribute76 option:selected').val());// empty in Chrome!
      if ($j('select#attribute76').val()=='')// empty in Chrome!
           $j('.infoOptionsColors a:first').click(); 
     });
```

What is happening is that Chrome is selecting the option that I am asking it to, but it reverts back somehow...  perhaps there is another call that is overriding it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know what the problem was.

I resolved it by moving my code towards the end of the javascript calls more.

The code that I moved it after seems barely related.. assigning the more to the .click function which is just adding/removing classes, and not changing any form values.  + some vide code..

Thanks @clockworkgeek for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know `$j('select#attribute76').val()` produces a value why not use that always instead of the longer `$j('select#attribute76 option:selected').val()` which doesn't work?

*Edit:*
I understand better. The value of a select can be an array since a select can also be a multiselect. When comparing with an empty string (`''`) most browsers make the shortcut of treating all empty values as equal, whether it is `0`, `NULL` or array with no items. I believe you might have better luck with

```
if (!$j('select#attribute76').val())
```

or by casting the returned value to a string

```
if (String($j('select#attribute76').val())=='')
```

Comment: I believe that I tried both.  I do use the shorter version in the program's code.. the IF..THEN uses the shorter, and is still returning empty.